# Why does python's `datetime.strptime` function not behave the same way when called using `functools.partial`?

Tags: python, datetime

Here is an example of the error that I am facing:

```
In [1]: from functools import partial                                                                                             

In [2]: from datetime import datetime                                                                                             

In [3]: datetime.strptime("2/3/2016", "%m/%d/%Y")                                                                                 
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 3, 0, 0)

In [4]: partial(datetime.strptime, "%m/%d/%Y")("2/3/2016")                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d803aff4879c> in <module>
----> 1 partial(datetime.strptime, "%m/%d/%Y")("2/3/2016")

~/miniconda3/envs/ROS/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py in _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format)
    563     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
    564     format string."""
--> 565     tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
    566     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
    567     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)

~/miniconda3/envs/ROS/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    360     if not found:
    361         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
--> 362                          (data_string, format))
    363     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    364         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %

ValueError: time data '%m/%d/%Y' does not match format '2/3/2016'
```

How do I get `datetime.strptime` to behave properly using `partial`? Is this a problem with how I am using `partial` or how I am using `datetime.strptime`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're passing the format (which is supposed to be the second parameter) as first to `strptime` via `partial`, and then passing the date string (which is supposed to be the first parameter), leading to the error.

You can't use `datetime.strptime` with `partial` like that as it does not take any keyword argument. Instead you can use a regular function:

```
In [246]: def get_dt(string): 
     ...:     return datetime.strptime(string, "%m/%d/%Y") 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [247]: get_dt("2/3/2016")                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[247]: datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 3, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to accept beemayl's answer. I just have a couple things to add that might be useful.

It's true the problem you saw was with the ordering of "arguments" to `partial`:

```
>>> from functools import partial  
>>> from datetime import datetime  
>>> datetime.strptime("2/3/2016", "%m/%d/%Y") 
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 3, 0, 0)
>>> partial(datetime.strptime, "%m/%d/%Y")("2/3/2016")
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ValueError: time data '%m/%d/%Y' does not match format '2/3/2016'
```

And indeed if you reverse the arguments, `partial` works:

```
>>> partial(datetime.strptime, "2/3/2016")("%m/%d/%Y")
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 3, 0, 0)
```

But this is not what you want, of course.

So, you might think you can take advantage of kwargs here...in fact, if you look at the docs, it says:

> classmethod datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
>
> Return a datetime corresponding to date_string, parsed according to format.

So let's try that:

```
>>> partial(datetime.strptime, format="%m/%d/%Y")("2/3/2016")
Traceback (most recent call last):
    TypeError: strptime() takes no keyword arguments
```

Takes no keyword arguments! WHAT?! Well yeah, most functions that "come from C" actually don't! By default, functions you write yourself in Python will always have kwargs, unless you use [the cool new feature starting in Python 3.8 that lets you prohibit them](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/).

Interestingly, if you make your *own* strptime:

```
>>> def my_strptime(date_string, format):
...     return datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
...
```

Then you *can* do what you want!

```
>>> partial(my_strptime, format="%m/%d/%Y")("2/3/2016")
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 3, 0, 0)
```

provided you use the kwarg `format`.